# Quando eu digito retirada e coloco o valor mais alto que o saldo o if não esta funcionando e barrando esta operação

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

std::string nome, menu;
float saldo, valor, saque;
using namespace std;
main()
{
    std::cout << "Digite seu nome: \n";
    std::cin >> nome;
    std::cout << "Digite o saldo: \n";
    std::cin >> saldo;
    std::cout << "Digite o valor: \n";
    std::cin >> valor;
    saque= valor-saldo;

    std::cout << "Digite uma das opcoes (saldo/deposito/retirada):\n";
    std::cin >> menu;

    if (menu == "deposito") {
        saldo = saldo + valor;
        printf("O saldo mais o valor depositado e igual a: %.2f\n", saldo);
    }else if (menu == "retirada") {
            if(saque>=0){
            saldo = saldo - valor;
            printf("O saldo menos o valor depositado e igual a: %.2f\n", saldo);
            }else if(saque<0){
                 printf("Nao foi possivel fazer a retirada, pois o valor que voce retirou e maior que o saldo da conta! \n");
            }
    }else if (menu == "saldo") {
        printf("O saldo e igual a: %.2f\n", saldo);
    }else {
        printf("Erro");
    }
}
```

Comment: barrando essa operação significa erro? Qual erro? senão qual resultado você esperava e qual está retornando atualmente?

Comment: Não deveria ser  saque= saldo-valor; ?

Answer (score 0):

O erro foi precisamente que o @Sveen já comentou. O seu calculo de `saque` não está correto:

```
saque= valor-saldo;
```

Se você tiver o `saldo` de `100` e `valor` de `50`, o seu `saque` vai ser `-50`. Por este motivo a instrução deveria ser ao contrario:

```
saque = saldo - valor;
```

E só com essa troca já vai funcionar como pretende. No entanto está a complicar excessivamente, e nem precisa dessa variável `saque`. Melhor é comparar diretamente no `if`:

```
}else if (menu == "retirada") {
    if(valor <= saldo){ //<----- compara direto aqui
        saldo -= valor; //<----- atualiza com o operador -= para ser mais curto
        printf("O saldo menos o valor depositado e igual a: %.2f\n", saldo);
    }else { //também já não precisa de else if aqui
        printf("Nao foi possivel fazer a retirada, pois o valor que voce retirou e maior que o saldo da conta! \n");
    }
}
```

Somente a comparação `valor <= saldo` já lhe diz se a retirada é valida ou não.

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/jBALW3)

Recomendações:

- Se utiliza sempre `std::` não faz sentido manter o `using namespace std;`, e acaba a poluir o *namespace*.
- Evite utilizar variáveis globais, assim como fez para todas as que tem no programa
- Mantenha a declaração de cada variável o mais perto possível da sua utilização ao invés de declarar tudo no topo